# Docker Volume is Empty after Mounting

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to set up a Docker-compose for my application(s) including a service based on the nginx image. I want to have the possibility to simply access the config from my Host. But when i mount the volume with

```
    volumes:
      - ./nginxConf:/etc/nginx
```

this volume is empty and the container crashes.

Full docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  frontend:
    image: myFrontend
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/v1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - "api"
    volumes:
      - ./nginxConf:/etc/nginx
  api:
    image: myApi
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "npm run build && npm run start"
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    links: 
      - mongo
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Show your entire docker-compose.yml file. Are you copying the .conf file into the container in the compose script?

Comment: I don't copy the file in the compose file. I want to see the default config file. (container -> host)

Comment: Volumes never work container -> host; they always mount what’s in the host directory over the content in the container.

Comment: Oh. I didn't knew about that. Thanks.

Comment: Found out that this won't work. [Anwere Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714686/docker-volume-is-empty-after-mounting?noredirect=1#comment101872566_57714686)